# Making a little game, stumbling on enemies

Tags: processing

Good evening everyone!
I am working on a little project for myself to understand processing a bit better, and I am going along pretty well. However, I have recently stumbled upon the problem that I do not know how to properly create multiple enemies.

As for now, the game is simple:
You can move around and shoot bullets, if you hit the white block, the block disappears and a new one spawns. 
Now I want to get multiple blocks to spawn, but I do now know how to do this without duplicating a lot of code (I'm very new to arrays so it's a bit complicated for me).
If anyone has any suggestions/examples that would be greatly appreciated.

```
PImage bg;

PImage shipUp;
PImage shipDown;
PImage shipLeft ;
PImage shipRight;
PImage prevDirection;

static final int WIDTH = 1080;
static final int HEIGHT = 720;
static final int SHIPSIZE = 40;

int shipLR = 0; //Variable for the ship to go left/right
int shipUD = 0; //Variable for the ship to go up / down
int stepSize = 20;
int enemySize = 60;
int score = 0;

float randomX;
float randomY;

int enemyCount;

boolean enemyHit = false;
```

---

### Creating the variables

```
//import processing.sound.*;
//SoundFile file;

//import controlP5.*;
//ControlP5 theControl;  
enum Direction {
  LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, LEFTUP, LEFTDOWN, RIGHTUP, RIGHTDOWN, STATIONARY
};

Direction direction = Direction.STATIONARY;

ArrayList <Bullet> bullets;//


void setup() {
  size(1080, 720);
  frameRate(60);
  bg = loadImage("Space2.jpg");
  bullets = new ArrayList();
  prevDirection = loadImage("Ship.jpg");
  shipUp = loadImage("Ship.jpg");
  shipDown = loadImage("ShipDown.jpg");  
  shipLeft = loadImage("ShipLeft.jpg");  
  shipRight = loadImage("ShipRight.jpg");
//  file = new SoundFile(this, "/Users/bruusriezebos/Documents/Processing/Shooter_Project/Music.mp3");
//  file.play();
}


void draw() {
  background(bg);
  shuttle(); //Call ship
  move(); //Allows you to move
  //enemyHit();
  removeToLimit(100); //Set the max amount of bullets to 100
  moveBullets(); //Move the bullets
  displayBullets(); //Show the bullets
  enemy(); //Spawn enemy
  //fill(255);
  //text(score,0,10);
}
```

---

### Setting up the draw and setup.

```
  void shuttle() {

  switch (direction) {
  case UP:
  case LEFTUP:
  case RIGHTUP:
    image(shipUp, shipLR, shipUD);
    prevDirection = shipUp;
    break;
  case DOWN:
  case LEFTDOWN:
  case RIGHTDOWN:
    image(shipDown, shipLR, shipUD);
    prevDirection = shipDown;
    break;
  case LEFT:
    image(shipLeft, shipLR, shipUD);
    prevDirection = shipLeft;
    break;
  case RIGHT:
    image(shipRight, shipLR, shipUD);
    prevDirection = shipRight;
    break;
  case STATIONARY:
    image(prevDirection, shipLR, shipUD);
    break;
  default:
    //Do nothing
  }
}
```

---

### Creating the spaceship

```
void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
  switch (key) {
  case 'l':
    Bullet temp = new Bullet(shipLR + (SHIPSIZE/2), shipUD + (SHIPSIZE/2), direction, 7.5);
    bullets.add(temp);
    break;
  case 'f':
    direction = Direction.LEFT;
    break;

  case 'h':
    direction = Direction.RIGHT;
    break;


  case 't':
    direction = Direction.UP;
    break;


  case 'g':
    direction = Direction.DOWN;
    break;

  case 'q':
    direction = Direction.LEFTUP;
    break;

  case 'e':
    direction = Direction.RIGHTUP;
    break;

  case 'z':
    direction = Direction.LEFTDOWN;
    break;

  case 'c':
    direction = Direction.RIGHTDOWN;
    break;

  default: 
    break;
  }
}
void move() {
  int lr = shipLR;
  int ud = shipUD;

  switch (direction) {
  case LEFT:
    lr = lr - stepSize;
    break;

  case RIGHT:
    lr = lr + stepSize;
    break;

  case UP:
    ud = ud - stepSize;
    break;

  case DOWN:
    ud = ud + stepSize;// Go down
    break;

  case LEFTUP:
    ud = ud - stepSize/2; //Diagonal movement
    lr = lr - stepSize/2; //Left + up
    break;

  case RIGHTUP:
    ud = ud - stepSize/2; //Diagonal movement
    lr = lr + stepSize/2; //Right + up
    break;

  case LEFTDOWN:
    ud = ud + stepSize/2; //Diagonal movement
    lr = lr - stepSize/2; //Left + down
    break;

  case RIGHTDOWN:
    ud = ud + stepSize/2; //Diagonal movement
    lr = lr + stepSize/2; //Right + down
    break;

  default: 
    break;
  }
  lr = constrain(lr, 0, WIDTH - SHIPSIZE ); //Constrain the ship in the window
  ud = constrain(ud, 0, HEIGHT - SHIPSIZE); //Constrain the ship in the window
  shipLR = lr;
  shipUD = ud;
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (key != 'l') {
    direction = Direction.STATIONARY;
  }
}
```

---

### The move function, which allows you to move and shoot.

```
class Bullet
{
  Direction bulletDirection;
  float bulletX;
  float bulletY;  
  float speed;
  Bullet(float bulletX, float bulletY, Direction bulletDirection, float speed)

  {
    this.bulletX = bulletX;
    this.bulletY = bulletY;
    this.bulletDirection =( bulletDirection == Direction.STATIONARY? Direction.UP: bulletDirection);
    this.speed = speed;
  }
  void display()
  {
    stroke(255);
    rectMode(CORNER);
    ellipse(this.bulletX, this.bulletY, 10, 10);
    {  
      if (dist(bulletX, bulletY, randomX + (enemySize / 2), randomY + (enemySize / 2) )<35) {
        enemyCount = - 1;
        score = score + 100;
        enemyHit = false;
      }
    }
  }
  void moveBullet() {
    switch (bulletDirection) {
    case UP:
      this.bulletY -= speed;
      break;
    case LEFT:
      this.bulletX -= speed;
      break;
    case RIGHT:
      this.bulletX += speed;
      break;
    case DOWN:
      this.bulletY += speed;
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}
void removeToLimit(int maxLength)
{
  while (bullets.size() > maxLength)
  {
    bullets.remove(0);
  }
}
void moveBullets()
{
  for (Bullet temp : bullets)
  {
    temp.moveBullet();
  }
}
void displayBullets()
{
  for (Bullet temp : bullets)
  {
    temp.display();
  }
}
```

---

### The bullet class, creating the bullets and moving them

```
void enemy() { 
  if (enemyCount < 10) {
    random();
    rect(randomX, randomY, enemySize, enemySize);
  }
  //if (enemyCount < 10) {
  //randomX = random(0, WIDTH - SHIPSIZE);
  //randomY = random(0, HEIGHT - SHIPSIZE);
  //enemyHit = true;
}

void random() { 
  if (enemyHit == false){
  randomX = random(0, WIDTH - SHIPSIZE);
  randomY = random(0, HEIGHT - SHIPSIZE);
  enemyHit = true;
  }
}
```

---

The enemy function, currently spawning only one block, and I would like to expand it to be creating more than 1. But my attempts at doing this efficiently haven't even been close enough to call worthwhile, so any ideas are very much appreciated.

I know this is a lot of code to throw at someone's direction, but I'm kind of at a loss here.

Comment: Far too much code for this site. See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it very similarly to your bullets, but use something else ( the previous enemy dying, a certain time has been reached etc) to trigger it.
You'd want to use an ArrayList for the enemies because the number of them would change with some frequency, and it's easier (possibly faster as well) to handle that situation using ArrayLists (as compared to arrays).